# How to prevent Gmail's preview pane from selecting the next message after deletion?

Tags: gmail

When I delete or archive a message in Gmail, it automatically shows the next message in the preview pane.

Is there any way to turn that off? I want the preview pane to show "No conversations selected" instead.

I have tried going to advanced settings, enabling auto-advance and then disabling it in general, but it does not work.

EDIT:

Seems like I presented an XY-problem, but what I want to achieve in the end is having the preview pane and being able to delete a mail without marking another mail as read, but at the same time, I want to mark mails i actively clicked on as read.

Comment: How would you get rid of the preview normally?

Comment: @Blindspots I have not found a good way to do it. I can reload the page. But on the other hand, I never have a need to do that. Maybe I asked an XY-problem. My main problem is that messages are marked as being read. I want them to be marked as read only when I manually read them. I guess I could as a workaround set the time for marking as read to 3 seconds and then reload after I have deleted a mail. But that feels very clunky.

Comment: I get it. I don't use that feature in Gmail and when I tested it earlier I didn't notice that it was marking them read. I always set Outlook preview to not mark as read when selection changes back in the day for the same reason as you. Not sure what to suggest. F5 is a quick page refresh, or you can automate something using an add-on to refresh it for you whenever you click archive or delete.  I did Automate sonething so that when I open a new tab in Gmail I'm returned to the original tab so if you can figure out exactly how to "undo" the behavior you could create an automation based on that.

Comment: Preview means you have read it.  You are trying to have it both ways.  Maybe use a 3rd party mail client.

Comment: @RohitGupta Well, if it didn't flip to another mail after deletion, my problem would be solved.